Method setProductLinks is very slow
I am looping trough 50.000 products. Most with linked items. But it takes forever. It can only handle 1-3 products/second? Is their a faster way than this?
ProductLinkInterfaceFactory $productLink,
ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,


*Loop*

$linkData = [];
$productLink = $this->productLink->create();
$productLink->setSku($SKU)
    ->setLinkedProductSku($item)
    ->setPosition($key)
    ->setLinkType('crosssell');
$linkData[] = $productLink;

$productLink = $this->productLink->create();
$productLink->setSku($SKU)
    ->setLinkedProductSku($item)
    ->setPosition($key)
    ->setLinkType('upsell');
$linkData[] = $productLink;


$product = $this->productRepository->get($SKU);
$product->setProductLinks($linkData);
$product->save();


We may follow some ways:
First, u can use API REST in bulk, bulk action execute in queue, so you can save in large volumes.
Endpoint: /async/bulk/V1/products
Example json:
[
  {
    "sku": "product_sku_1",
    "name": "Product Name 1",
    "price": 100,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 4,
    "type_id": "simple",
    "attribute_set_id": 4,
    "extension_attributes": {},
    "custom_attributes": []
  },
  {
    "sku": "product_sku_2",
    "name": "Product Name 2",
    "price": 200,
    "status": 1,
    "visibility": 4,
    "type_id": "simple",
    "attribute_set_id": 4,
    "extension_attributes": {},
    "custom_attributes": []
  }
]

doc: https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/rest/use-rest/bulk-endpoints/
Second, u can create a script to insert directly into database, so it executes in seconds.
Third, u can use the save method with batches.
Last, u can import data products with csv.
At System -> Data Transfer -> Import
Select Products in flied entity type
Make upload of a file csv.
